# Resharper 8.1 Test Runner slowing down Visual Studio Text Editing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, vs-unit-testing-framework, visual-studio-test-runner, resharper-8.1

I've got a fairly small C# solution with about 5 projects in it. I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Update 4, and Resharper 8.1 (build 8.1.23.546). It's on an I7 with an SSD and 16GB RAM, with oodles of disk space. Performance on this machine is fantastic for everything else.

I have R# set to be my unit test runner, and I've noticed that as soon as I run any unit tests (one or many, pass or fail, makes no difference), the Visual Studio text editor becomes almost unusable. Typing into the editor window suffers such extreme lag (up to 1 second between keystrokes) that it completely breaks down the development flow. Sometimes I actually have to stop typing to let the keystrokes catch up so that I can look up something in Intellisense.

The problem persists until I close down and then reopen VS, at which point everything is fine again. Until I run another unit test. Then it's back again.

I've run Process Monitor to see if that turned up anything (it didn't), and I've tried various things like cleaning out various caches, temporary asp.net files, resetting settings, all to no effect, in fact basically pretty much all the options presented at [Google search results for VS being really slow](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=Visual%20studio%202012%20typing%20really%20slowly)

However, process of elimination did eventually narrow everything down to being a problem with Resharper, and specifically the test runner.

I then tried the R# performance optimisation tips as described [here - The Ultimate Guide to speeding up Resharper](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Ultimate+Guide+to+Speeding+Up+ReSharper+%28and+Visual+Studio%29), and the only one that worked (after many restarts) was the disabling the Unit Test Runner.

I've since disabled the R# test runner, and reverted to the built-in VS one (which I hate), and the problem went away immediately. As soon as I re-enable the R# test runner, the problem comes back.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and found a solution?

Cheers :)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Typing is fast in normal files, but when I edit a unit test file, it lags. I thought it was code analysis that was doing it because using Ctrl+Alt+Shift+8 (disable code analysis for the current file) seemed to help. However, non-unit test files were fine. Then I unchecked "Enable Unit Testing" and the problem went away regardless of the code analysis settings. I do not have a solution.

Comment: @JeremyRoberts I think this may have been fixed with a new R# version (8.2.x EAP), see my answer below? Hopefully it works for you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in the latest 8.2 EAP build (I downloaded and installed 8.2.0.1139 this morning). I closed VS2012, install R# and get it to remove conflicting products.

When I reopened VS, it had clobbered all the R# extension tools (presumably because it's not a stable build). I also told it to disable support for NUnit (because we're not using it) in the unit testing options (tho this made no difference before).

I can now run unit tests using the R# runner (it's a LOT quicker as well), and there's no enforced typing-speed slowdown in the IDE any more.

Answer (score 1):

I have improved my performance by going to *CodeMaid -> Configuration... -> Digging (Spade) -> General* and unchecking "Synchronize outlining with the code file." Resharper code analysis and unit testing is on.

```
Visual Studio 2013
Resharper 8.1.23.546
CodeMaid 0.7.0
```