# Horrible Visual Studio 2013 Performance

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 has been a nightmare.  There seems to be a long delay between when I press a key and when it appears in the code editor window.  When I scroll, either in the code editor or in the navigation pane, it takes many seconds.  I've had similar problems with VS 2010 and VS 2012 (see [Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate slow while editing C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751996/visual-studio-2012-ultimate-slow-while-editing-c-sharp-code)).  Another person had a similar problem, none of their solutions helped me with mine ([Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate slow while editing C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751996/visual-studio-2012-ultimate-slow-while-editing-c-sharp-code)).

My machine is running Windows 8.1, has an Intel i7 and 16GB of RAM, and a Samsung SSD.  It's pretty fast.

What I've experienced:
Visual Studio absolutely hammers the registry per Process Monitor

- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider Types\Type 001 HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider
  Types\Type 001\Name HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid
- HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions, HKCU\Software\Classes
- HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\DESHashSessionKeyBackward
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider\Microsoft
  Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0\Image Path

Processor Monitor also shows that, when I attempt to interact with the code in any way, VS literally kicks off about 85,000 events, all containing access to files in the project and the registry keys listed above.  There are also a lot of 'NotifyChangeDirectory' events to my user home directory and a lot of 'Thread Create' and 'Thread Exit' events.

What I've tried:

- deleting files/folders in the AppData temp directory unchecked
- hardware graphics acceleration (Tools > Options > Environment)
- disabled source control plugin (Tools > Options > Source Control)
- disabled synchronized settings (Tools > Options > Environment)
- disabled auto recover (Tools > Options > Auto Recover) reinstalling
- SQL server compact edition 4.0 deleting the .SUO file disabled
- codelens rebooting (too many times)

This behavior also happens when I start Visual Studio in safe mode.

Per Task Manager, Visual Studio isn't consuming a lot of CPU/RAM (up to 3% CPU, 150MB of RAM).  Additionally, not using BitLocker, disk is unencrypted, and no add-ins are installed in Visual Studio.

This is really, really bad.  It's become practically unusable.  If anyone has any idea how to fix this, I will be in your debt.

Comment: Did you check if there is any plugins that runs with your visual studio

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like you've got some bad extensions or plug ins in your VS. If you haven't done this already, try going through your "Tools|Extensions and Updates". After that, check your "Tools|Add in Manager".

Comment: Is there anything unusual about your hard drives, file system or encryption settings?

Comment: Antivirus should be kept away from your working folders and from your VS folders. Well I don't think that this could be the cause of a so massive slowness but nevertheless....

Comment: Hi all, unencrypted drive, not using BitLocker, no antivirus, and no extensions added by me other than those that were default with VS.

Comment: What version control type?  And how is it configured?

Comment: Are you connected to a domain (remote profile?) or running Google Drive/OneDrive/Box etc type tools?

Comment: Hi, I disabled the source control plug-in.  This project is not connected to any version control.

Comment: And the folder (regardless of the project) isn't still mapped to TFS or Git in any way?

Comment: Have you tried signing-out from you Visual Studio account? Does it happen when you start from a fresh local user profile?

Comment: Hi Jesse, version control is set to none.  This is a personal machine and not part of a domain.  The folder is not mapped to git.  I'll try signing out of Visual Studio to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Signing out of Visual Studio did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it.

I really hope this keeps someone from jumping off the bridge.

NoGit is a great extension, but ultimately it came down to removing the registry entries for the Git source control provider.

http://blog.markrendle.net/disable-the-git-source-control-add-in-in-vs2013-permanently/